# question about using np.logical_and in an np.where statement

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider a small sample of the 4-column array Q.  My goal is to eliminate rows of Q where **BOTH columns 0 and 2 are equal, AND columns 1 and 3 are equal**.  So, `[1, 2, 1, 2]` needs to go, as does `[3, 4, 3, 4]`.  I thought the following code would work.

```
import numpy as np

Q = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 2],
              [1, 2, 1, 4],
              [2, 4, 3, 4],
              [3, 4, 3, 4],
              [4, 7, 2, 5]])

output = Q[np.where(np.logical_and(Q[:,0] != Q[:, 2], Q[:,1] != Q[:, 3]))]
print(output)

[[4 7 2 5]]
```

This code eliminates the desired two rows, but it also removes `[1, 2, 1, 4]` and `[2, 4, 3, 4]`.

In other words, it is doing:
"**remove the record if V[:,0] != V[:, 2], and also remove the record if V[:,1] != V[:, 3]**".

I'd wanted it to:
"**remove the record if BOTH V[:,0] != V[:, 2]  AND  V[:,1] != V[:, 3]**".
Isn't that what logical_and means?

Any insights into what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe as your desired output is:

```
output = Q[~((Q[:,0]==Q[:,2]) * (Q[:,1]==Q[:,3]))]
```

or equally:

```
output = Q[~(np.logical_and(Q[:,0]==Q[:,2], Q[:,1]==Q[:,3]))]
```

or equally:

```
output = Q[np.logical_or(Q[:,0]!=Q[:,2], Q[:,1]!=Q[:,3])]
```

or equally:

```
output = Q[(Q[:,0]!=Q[:,2]) + (Q[:,1]!=Q[:,3])]
```

But I would prefer it this way (which probably is faster):

```
output = Q[(Q[:,0:2]!=Q[:,2:]).any(1)]
```

Note that you do not need `np.where`. The boolean mask applies to rows of the array `Q`.

output:

```
[[1 2 1 4]
 [2 4 3 4]
 [4 7 2 5]]
```

Comment: @user109387 You are welcome. I personally prefer `output = Q[(Q[:,0:2]!=Q[:,2:]).any(1)]`, but it also depends on how this simplified question applies to your specific problem. Added this to the answer as well.